# When would I want to use “class” (static) methods or properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, static-methods, coffeescript, prototypal-inheritance

In JavaScript, why would one want to attach properties directly to the constructor?

```
var Human = function() {};
Human.specie = "Homo Sapience";
```

I've got this question after looking at CoffeeScript‘s `__extend` helper function, which contains, among the lines:

```
for ( var key in parent ) { 
  if ( __hasProp.call( parent, key ) ) child[key] = parent[key]; 
}
```

which copies properties / methods to the subclassed object directly from the constructor object. But why would anybody do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short the answer to the question posted is **name spacing**. There are certain values that may have sense to be shared across your program and that semantically have to do with certain class. These functions and values could be just put in some variables, but attaching them to constructor function is practical in order to namespace them.

The best example is JavaScript `Math` class (for purists, I know it's not really a class, it's an object):

```
// There are constants
Math.E
Math.PI
Math.SQRT2
// And there are also methods
Math.ceil
Math.cos
Math.sin
```

So the methods and values (saved in constants) are always the same and they don't depend on instance that they are being called on and it makes no sense to have them on instances.

Answer (score 2):

(**Edit:** In its original form, the question asked about attaching properties to classes vs. attaching them to prototypes, so that's what I'm responding to.)

It's really more a matter of convention than anything else. If you write

```
Human::specie = "Homo sapiens"
```

(where `Human::specie` is CoffeeScript shorthand for `Human.prototype.specie`) then declare `jane = new Human`, then `jane.specie` will be `"Homo sapiens"` (unless you specifically set `jane.specie` to something else). In this case, that sounds desirable.

But in other cases, having a property shared across a large number of prototypes makes your code harder to understand. Let's say that you have a `Logger` class with a `config` object. If you attached that object to the prototype, then you could write code like this:

```
log = new Logger
log.config.destination = './foo'
```

This would change the destination of *all* `Logger` instances to `'./foo'`, because there's only one `config` object. If you want `config` to apply to all `Logger` instances, then you should attach it to the class proper, removing the ambiguity from the code above:

```
log = new Logger
Logger.config.destination = './foo'
```

Comment: I'm sorry for editing the question, it seemed it slightly missed the main point when it was that long. In your example, I am not sure I understand why changing one instance‘s property (`log.config`) would affect other instances – we aren't changing the prototype, by modifying one instances property / method. Thanks!

Comment: Because `Logger::config == log.config`—they're actually the same object. (I talk about this a bit in [my CoffeeScript book](http://pragprog.com/titles/tbcoffee/coffeescript).) If you set `log.config = something`, that wouldn't affect other `Logger` instances. But if you write `log.config.x = y`, that's equivalent to `Logger::config.x = y`.

Comment: Is a better way of saying that, Trevor, Logger::config == Logger.prototype.config which can be accessed via log.config?

Comment: @c3rin Either statement is accurate, provided that `log.hasOwnProperty('config')` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In a game say you have an object called world.  However there will only ever be one world in the game.  This is theoretically the reason you would do this.

Comment: but then, wouldn't you better off using `var world = { //... };` anyway?

Comment: well of course when creating the object you put your initial values in the constructor, but for changing it later you just do world.population = 6775235700;

Comment: what I meant is why would you even have any class to describe object, if it's going to have single instance in the end, since you could just describe it using literal notation.

Comment: it is more logical to have world.growth = 2; and world.population = 6775235700; than just having growth = 2; and population = 6775235700;

with a static class the programmer has a more clear understanding that these two variables are related.

Comment: which means that you will use your constructor as a name space, which you could still do by simple using object literal: `var world = { growth : 2 };`

Comment: So your question is essentially, "Do I use a namespace or not?"  Your question is something like deciding weather to eat an apple or an orange.  It just depends on how much you want to organize your code.  I often find myself in most projects never needing more than one namespace.  It often takes a mid-size large project to even consider it.  I take my approach the most because the code and is to the point.  Your method is just as correct.  It is simply just a more organized way of doing things.